# How to change language and input settings programmatically?

Tags: android, input, settings, application-settings

**Problem**

I don't know how I can change the "Language and input" settings manually.

**What I know**

For example I know how to change the "Display" settings programmatically:

```
Settings.System.putInt(cResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 255);
Settings.System.putInt(cResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 600000);
```

**What I need to know**

- I need to know how the Language (first screenshot) can be changed programmatically. => Not for my app. For the whole device.
- I need to know how "Smart typing" (second screenshot) can be changed programmatically.

**Question**

Is it even possible to change those Language & Input Settings by code?

**Screenshots**

[image: Language Settings]

[image: Keyboard Settings]

Comment: which screeshots are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry... I forgot to upload those screenshots. I have edited my question.

Comment: For the latter, ask Samsung, as that is a Samsung thing, not an Android thing. For the former, I doubt that it can be changed, except perhaps on rooted devices.